# RecycerView always reset back to first position after inserting new Firebase data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

My recyclerview always reset to first position after new data is inserted to firebase. In my TestAdapter class, I have an onClickListener which increments like on a post when clicked. Whenever I click on this "like" button, view is reset to first position. I believe this issue is related to setAdapter() being called on data changed. Please help!

**MainActivity** fetches "post" data from Firebase and populates it in TestAdapter class.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private TestAdapter testAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Post> postList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        fetchPostFromDB();

    }


    private void fetchPostFromDB() {

        DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Post");
        databaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                postList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String post = snap.child("post").getValue().toString();
                    Post post = new Post(post);
                    postList.add(post);
                }

                testAdapter = new TestAdapter(getApplicationContext(), postList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(testAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

**TestAdapter** binds the data (postList) and has an onClickListener.

```
public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TestAdapter.TestHolder> {

    private List<Post> postList;
    private Context context;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    public TestAdapter(Context ct, ArrayList<Post> postList) {
        context = ct;
        this.postList = postList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TestHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.post_item, parent, false);
        final TestHolder holder = new TestHolder(view);

        holder.ibLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String postID = postList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getPostID();
                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").child(postID).child("likes");
                int incrementLike = postList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getLikes() + 1;
                databaseReference.setValue(incrementLike);
            }
        });

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final TestHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.tvPost.setText(postList.get(position).getPost());
        holder.tvVotes.setText(Integer.toString(postList.get(position).getLikes()));
  
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return postList.size();
    }

 public static class TestHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvPost, tvLikes;
        ImageButton ibLike;

        public TestHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvPost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPost);
            tvLikes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLikes);
            ibLike = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ibLike);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Define and set your adapter outside the onDataChange method, and update the list inside this method and notify the adapter for datasetchanged.

Comment: @Ankit where do i notify the adapter for datasetchanged?

Comment: In your onDataSetChange method, update the list which you passed in your adapter and after adding items, on next line, call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here need to initialize your adapter class from main activity. and then when data received just call `adapter.notifiyDatasetChanged` like:
onCreate():

```
postList = new ArrayList<>();
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
testAdapter = new TestAdapter(getApplicationContext(), postList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(testAdapter);
```

and from your `fetchPostFromDB` delete adapter initialization insted of this just put this line `testAdapter.notifiyDataSetChanged()`

And when click on text button you can update/handle like this:

```
holder.ibLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String postID = postList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getPostID();
                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").child(postID).child("likes");
                int incrementLike = postList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getLikes() + 1;
                postList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setLikes(incrementLike);
                databaseReference.setValue(incrementLike);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Ok, when I click on the button, it doesn't update the textview anymore.

Comment: The data in firebase is changed on click, but it is not rendering. Any thoughts?

Comment: added the notifyDataSetChanged(); but textview still isn't updating in real time.

Comment: You should add also this line `postList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setLikes(incrementLike)`